# Directive template from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make my directive load in a template based on it's controller variable.  The other questions I've seen on here rely on a string being passed into the directive instead of grabbing it from the controller.

Directive:

```
import {LanguageController} from "./language.controller.ts";

export class LanguageSelectDirective {
    static NAME: string = "selectLanguage";


    static factory(): ng.IDirective {

        let directive = {
            restrict: "E",
            link: function() {},
            templateUrl: function(elem, attrs){
                return "./" + attrs.language + "/language.html"
            },
            scope: {
                language: "@"
            },
            controller: LanguageController,
            controllerAs: "lc",
            bindToController: true
        };

        return directive;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
export class LanguageController{
   private selectedLanguage: String;
   //More stuff
}
```

Template:

```
<select-language ng-hide="authenticated" language="{{lc.selectedLanguage}}"></select-language>
```

The error I keep seeing is:

`GET http://localhost:3000/%7B%7Blc.selectedLanguage%7D%7D/language.html 404 (Not Found)`

How can I force it to evaluate the language parameter as a controller variable instead of as a literal string?

Comment: Try

    <select-language ng-hide="authenticated" language="lc.selectedLanguage"></select-language>

...you don't need the `{{}}` curly braces

Comment: Can use `ng-include`

Comment: I think @charlieftl is right -- ng-include is the way to go. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<select-language ng-hide="authenticated" language="lc.selectedLanguage"></select-language>
```

...you don't need the `{{}}` curly braces

Here's a plnkr using angular 1.4: http://plnkr.co/edit/HOjKKm

And here's the directive function:

```
let directive={
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        language: '=', //= not @ ensures the model value is interpreted
        'content': '=' //we are binding to an object
      },
      template:  '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"></ng-include>',
      controller: function($scope){
        $scope.getTemplateUrl=function(){
          return $scope.language+'_language.html';
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `{{}}` on the directive definition, and also use '=' in your scope definition.

```
<select-language ng-hide="authenticated" language="lc.selectedLanguage"></select-language>
```

Comment: I've tried this as well, but it still uses the string `lc.selectedLanguage` instead of evaluating

Comment: Can you confirm that lc is a `$scope` object?